# ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]

Tags: azure

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open server 'testdbsqlserver2' requested by the login. Client with IP address '40.119.236.175' is not allowed to access the server.

I cannot connect my server to my web app.

Answer (score 0):

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open server 'testdbsqlserver2' requested by the login. Client with IP address '40.119.236.175' is not allowed to access the server.

You can solve the above error by following below process:

- Firstly, Open Azure Portal
- Then click on your SQL server.
- Click the networking property under Security Section.
- Then add a firewall rule and give a name ans the IP Address **40.119.236.175**
- You can give start and end the same IP address .

[image]